# Form elements are misaligned

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the problem where ,y form is not aligning correctly when using flex box.

```css
/* Article Styling Definitions */
article {
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

#article_left {
  flex: 1;
  align-content: center;
}

#article_right {
  flex: 1;
  align-content: center;
}

.cta {
  flex: 30;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

form > div {
  flex: 45%;
}

.label {
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id="article_left">
      <p>Call Us</p>
    </div>
    <div id="article_right">
      <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
      <form id="contact_form">
        <div class="label">
          <label for="contact_name">Full name:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="contact_phone">Mobile number:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input type="tel" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" placeholder="Mobile number">
        </div>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="contact_email">Email address:</label>
        <div>
          <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="E-mail address">
        </div>
        <div class="label">
          <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>                 
        </div>
        <div>
          <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact+message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

I am currently studying and am completing an assessment, but I just can't work this out.

[image: formatting issues - image]

If you can assist me that would be amazing - this is a basic assignment but the flexbox is throwing everything out of whack (we have to use flex box)

Comment: Attach the view you want.

Comment: using flex is irrelevant here, because the expected output you have dont have that structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

```css
/* Article Styling Definitions */
article {
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

#article_left {
  flex: 1;
  align-content: center;
}

#article_right {
  flex: 1;
  align-content: center;
}

.cta {
  flex: 30;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 25px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}


.input-box {
  padding-right: 5px;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  width: 45%;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}
input, textarea {
  width: 55%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>
    <div id="article_left">
      <p>Call Us</p>
    </div>
    <div id="article_right">
      <h2>Contact Us!</h2>
      <form id="contact_form">
        <div class="input-box">
          <label for="contact_name">Full name:</label>
          <input type="text" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <label for="contact_phone">Mobile number:</label>
          <input type="tel" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" placeholder="Mobile number">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <label for="contact_email">Email address:</label>
          <input type="email" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" placeholder="E-mail address">
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <label for="contact_message">Message:</label>               
          <textarea rows="4" cols="40" id="contact_message" name="contact+message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you did in the code?

Comment: This didn't work - https://imgur.com/a/DKC9awv